# c# how to delete an item in an array?

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine ("Enter the number of book to delete (1 to {0})", amount);
int posToDelete = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ())-1;

for (int i = posToDelete; i < amount - 1; i++)
b [i] = b [i + 1];
 amount--;

// hi! i am new to programming... could anyone please explain this to me in detail
```

// * what is the use of -1 after the readline
   // * explain me the loop plz

```
//link of the question
//http://practiceexercisescsharp.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/411-books-database.html
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to show us what research you have done, tests you have run, and then request clarification of said research. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your questions.

Comment: chances are you want a `List<T`> instead of an array, lists natively support adding removing items, arrays don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## fisrt question:

An array is start from 0.
for example: There is an array b includes 4 elements.

```
b[4] = {1,2,3,4};
```

so `b[0]` is `1` and `b[3]` is `4`.
there is no `b[4]`.

if you want to delete the second item(which element is `2`) ,you should delete `b[1]`.
so the position is `1`.
This is why we use `-1` after the readline.

## second question:

```
for (int i = posToDelete; i < amount - 1; i++)
{
    b [i] = b [i + 1];
    amount--;
}
```

`int = posToDelete` is the position of the item we want to delete.
we use the next item to replace it.
this is `b[i] = b[i+1];`
because we delete one item,the amount need `-1`;
we also use `b[4]` for example:
if we delete `2`.
initial:`[1,2,3,4]` `amount=4`;
loop begin: [1,2,3,4] `posDelete` is `1`,`amount` is `3`;
`b[1]=b[2];`we use `3` to replace `2`;
`b[2]=b[3];`we use `4` to replace `3`;
`i` is increasing until `i` is `3`;the loop end.
the new array is `[1,3,4]`.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the `indexer` of your book array is layout like the following:

```
book[0] = "Book1" //Where user inputs 1 and then subtract 1 from it to access index 0
```

Consider the following examples:

```
book[0] = "Book1" //Book input is 1 less 1 = index of 0
book[1] = "Book2" //Book input is 2 less 1 = index of 1
book[2] = "Book3" //Book input is 3 less 1 = index of 2
```

Of course the logic of deleting the book is in question, since we are not sure how the book is really arranged in `Arrays` or `Collections.` But in your case, you are specifying the **position** so it can be said that **position 1 is 
equal to index 0**.